# Could you explain why is the result this: [ [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ] ] and not this: [[0,0], [0,0,0,0] ]?

Tags: javascript

```
function zeroArray(m,n){
  let newArray = []; 
  let row = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < m; i++){
     for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        row.push(0);
     }
     newArray.push(row);
  }
  return newArray;
}
let matrix = zeroArray(2, 2);
console.log(matrix)
```

The first row (after first for loop) is [[0,0]] but next time its [[0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0]]. And I have no idea why the first row changed. Could you explain? I know that I could reset "row" after newArray.push(row) but then the result would be [[0,0], [0,0]] but I want this result: [[0,0], [0,0,0,0]].

Comment: You never reset your `row` to empty array. Maybe you need to move it inside first `for`?

Comment: But if I reset it, the result would be [[0,0], [0,0]]. And I want the result to be [[0,0], [0,0,0,0]]

Answer (score 2):

The `row` is the same array when you push to `newArray`. Create a copy and push will solve the problem.

```js
function zeroArray(m,n){
  let newArray = []; 
  let row = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < m; i++){
     for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        row.push(0);
     }
     newArray.push([...row]);
  }
  return newArray;
}
let matrix = zeroArray(2, 2);
console.log(matrix)
```

Answer (score -1):

Move the `row` declaration into the first `for` loop, so it resets between the first and the second row.